# Topological spaces with isomorphic categories of open subsets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Given two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, let $\text{Op}(X)$ (resp. $\text{Op}(Y)$) be the [category of open subsets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+open+subsets) of $X$ (resp. $Y$). If the two categories $\text{Op}(X)$ and $\text{Op}(Y)$ are isomorphic, under what conditions can we say that $X$ and $Y$ are also isomorphic? What kind of information of $X$ can we learn from $\text{Op}(X)$? More importantly, what if $X$ is a quasi-projective variety (Zarski topology)?

Comment: What is the category of open subsets of $X$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Please check the updated link.

Comment: Isn’t it for sober spaces that we can say they’re isomorphic?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Do you mean the equivalence of $\text{OP}(X), \text{OP}(Y)$ implies the sober spaces $X, Y$ are homeomorphic? I think it's true.

Comment: I think I read that somewhere. My memory could be off though. Maybe in the book “Stone spaces”?

Comment: Prop. 3.4 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sober+topological+space) comes close.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks! After reading your comments and Арсений's answer, I also noticed that page.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Another version of what you’re saying, that is maybe more useful in theoretical considerations, is that equivalences of *topoi* between the sheaves on $X$ and $Y$ come from homeomorphisms of their soberifications $X^\mathrm{sob}\cong Y^\mathrm{sob}$.

Comment: So it seems that if $\text{Op}(X)$ is isomorphic to $\text{Op}(Y)$ we can say that the topological spaces $X^{\text{sob}}$ and $Y^{\text{sob}}$ are homeomorphic and so $X \simeq Y$ if both spaces were sober to start with.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't answer your question entirely but I hope it will help.

The idea to consider categories of opens instead of points of spaces leads to the so-called locales. A locale is a poset with finite intersections and all unions (products and coproducts), which is distributive. Morphisms of locales are morphisms that commute with all that structure, except that we take an opposite category, because a map of posets $\mathcal O (X) \to \mathcal O (Y)$ corresponds to the map $Y \to X$ in the opposite direction.

Now, a point of a locale $L$ is a map $\{0,1\} \to L$ (because it's a map from the final object, like in $\text{Top}$). A point of a space $p \in X$ determines a point $\bar{p}$ of a locale $\mathcal O (X)$ as a map of posets $\mathcal O (X) \to \{0,1\}$ such that it equals $0$ on those subsets $V \subset X$ that do not contain $x$.  When the opposite is true, the space is called *sober*. More precisely, a sober space is a space $X$ such that for all $P \in O (X)$ satisfying

$P \not = X$
and $U \cap V \subset P \implies U \subset P \text{ or } V \subset P$

[here we are inspired by the properties of those points $\bar{p}$ of $\mathcal O (X)$ that come from $p \in X$], there is a unique point $x$ such that $P$ in the complement of the closure of $x$.

Points of locales can be topologized, which gives rise to the adjunction
$\text{loc}: \text{Top}\substack{\rightarrow \\[-0.1ex] \leftarrow} \text{Loc}: \text{pt}.$
A space is homeomorphic to points of its locale (via the unit of this adjunction) precisely when it's sober.